# Unable to identify Google Chrome Window using AutoHotkey

Tags: google-chrome, autohotkey

I am trying to use AutoHotkey to activate the top most Google Chrome window. This is the code I am using:

```
WinActivate, ahk_class Chrome_WidgetWin_1
```

However, it does not seem to have any effect.

Trying

```
WinGet nChromeWindows, Count, ahk_class Chrome_WidgetWin_1
```

makes the `nChromeWindows` variable get a value that is more than 1, even when only a single chrome window is open. This indicates that the reason the WinActivate above does not work correctly is that multiple Chrome "windows" seem to exist even when there is only one "actual" one.

Can anyone explain what is going on and how to identify the "real" (topmost) Chrome window?

TIA, Himanshu

Comment: Do you have a `SetTitleMatchMode` set?  I have mine as `SetTitleMatchMode, 2` followed by your WinActivate line, and it grabs the topmost Chrome window successfully.

Answer (score 4):

Google Chrome creates multiple child processes and the each process owns a window including background windows for Chrome extensions or tabs. So you need to find out the oldest process, the parent process of all, and activate the window which the oldest one is using.

Press control+1 to see if it works. Make sure you have the latest AutoHotkey version.

```
^1::WinActivate, % "ahk_pid " GetOldestPIDFromProcessName("chrome.exe")

GetOldestPIDFromProcessName(strProcessName) {

    for oProc in ComObjGet("winmgmts:").ExecQuery("Select ProcessID,CreationDate from Win32_Process WHERE Name = '" strProcessName "'") {           
        nOldestPID := (nOldestPIDCreationDate > oProc.CreationDate) ? oProc.ProcessID : nOldestPID ? nOldestPID : oProc.ProcessID
        nOldestPIDCreationDate := oProc.CreationDate    
    }
    return nOldestPID
}
```

Comment: Haven't tried it yet, but it sounds promising. However my intent is to activate the *topmost* chrome window if there are more than one. 
It doesn't seem like this will handle that, right? Is there a way to fix that?

Comment: Ah, I will. Just wanted to know if you reckon that it'll handle the case I am talking about, before I spend time trying it. It will probably take you a few seconds to answer, white me trying it actually will require *minutes* ;)

Comment: I tried the code and it's working well for my requirement. Except, how can I change the function so that I can exclude it from returning a process where the window has a certain title? (The window in question is created by a extension called "Tabs Outliner", so its not a "real" chrome window, but its ID gets returned nonetheless if it's the topmost window).
Also, can you explain how your code works/point to resources that would. I have a lot of AHK experience but have never used ComObjGet() (and have only limited WinAPI experience in general).

Comment: It was a long shot, but trying `ExecQuery("Select ProcessID,CreationDate from Win32_Process WHERE Name = '" strProcessName "' AND Title != 'Tabs Outliner' ")` didn't seem to work.

Comment: Realized there was an unnecessary single quote before AND above^, but removing that didn't help either.

Comment: I suggest you start a new question.

Answer (score 2):

This worked from me:

```
; Activate an existing chrome.exe window, or open a new one
if WinExist("ahk_exe chrome.exe")
    WinActivate, ahk_exe chrome.exe
else
    Run, "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe"
```

I found this on http://l.autohotkey.net/docs/misc/WinTitle.htm